# cannot subscript a value of type '[Int16]'

Tags: swift

Here is the relevant code:

```
/// Individual audio samples
let samples: [Int16]

/// The rates in Hz
let sampleRate: Int

/// The part of the audio which is a vowel utterance
lazy var vowelPart: Range<Int> = {
    let strongPart = SpeechAnalyzer2.findStrongPartOfSignal(self.samples, withChunks: 300, sensitivity: 0.1)
    let clippedPart = SpeechAnalyzer2.truncateTailsOfRange(strongPart, portion: 0.15)
    return clippedPart
}()

private lazy var vowelSamplesDecimated: [Int16] = {
    let out = SpeechAnalyzer2.decimateSamples(self.samples[self.vowelPart], withFactor: 4)
    return out
}()
```

The `out = ...` line at the bottom gives the error:

> cannot subscript a value of type '[Int16]'

First, how is such an error message even valid (of course you can subscript an array!). And secondly, how can I fix this in the instant case?

---

Update, after accepting Nate's answer, here is how I updated the downstream function to be generic on `CollectionType` for future reference:

```
/// Select the first of every `factor` items from `samples`
class func decimateSamples<T: CollectionType where T.Index: Strideable>(samples: T, withStride stride: T.Index.Stride) -> Array<T.Generator.Element> {
    let selectedSamples = samples.startIndex.stride(to: samples.endIndex, by: stride)
    return selectedSamples.map({samples[$0]})
}
```

Comment: What's the full error message? Usually after `cannot subscript` comes a `with an index of type `

Comment: I've had a similar error yesterday and I think it might have to do with the function you are passing to.

Comment: @Cristik this is the *entire* error message, that's what's killing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `decimateSamples` method must take an `[Int16]` array as its parameter. Unfortunately, when you subscript an array with a range like `vowelPart`, you get an `ArraySlice<Int16>`, not an array of the same type. The easy solution is to convert your slice to a new array:

```
... decimateSamples(Array(self.samples[self.vowelPart]), withFactor: 4) ...
```

That ends up duplicating the contents of the array, which isn't good if it's a large dataset. You can instead make your function accept either an `Array` or an `ArraySlice` by making it generic for any kind of `CollectionType`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, performance was an issue. I just learned Swift generics and implemented it downstream (basically just descended one level deeper into hell). Per your preferred suggestion, this allowed to avoid duplicating the array at this stage. (Solution appended to question.)

Comment: Of course, the compiler error could be much improved. I assume the logic is that ArraySlice<Int16> is similar to Array<Int16> and it just prints as [Int16]. That oversimplification is what started this whole learning experience.